# How figure out what actual type in scala?

Tags: scala, types, traits

There is one trait with type declaration. I can not figure out what the actual `SomeType` type is? Here is the code:

```
package someModel {
    trait SomeTrait extends Serializable {
            type SomeType
            def id: SomeType
        }    
}
```

**Important notes**

- There is no imports in someModel file.
- Serializable is scala.Serializable
- `type SomeType` appear in `SomeTrait` **only**. Not somewhere down in the file.

Comment: You have a possibility to change / add smth inside trait `SomeTrait`?

Comment: Do not fully understand what you meant, but this trait should be used like `class BlaBla with SomeTrait`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `SomeType` is not an actual type (yet), it's an *abstract type member*, abstract because the mixing classes will have to provide an implementation for it:

```
trait SomeTrait extends Serializable {
  type SomeType
  def id: SomeType
}

class SomeClass extends SomeTrait {
  type SomeType = Int

  def id: SomeType = 1
}

class SomeOtherClass extends SomeTrait {
  type SomeType = Long

  def id: SomeType = 2L
}
```

For difference between generics and type member there's [this great SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154571/scala-abstract-types-vs-generics) post

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what "actual type" in your question means.

1. If you want to know what `SomeType` is going to be, it's impossible, since it's not declared yet.
2. If you're asking how to refer to `SomeType` of some `SomeTrait` instance during the **compile time**, then just call `foo.SomeType` where `foo` is `SomeTrait`.
3. If it's in need during the **run time** where the type info has been erased, you have to make the instances carry it within something. [Here sees how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491076/scala-how-to-write-a-getnamestring-typeclass-for-map/25497186#25497186)

I hope I got your idea :)